# XPath not returning results - YouTube feed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, xpath

I am trying to use XPath in C# to fetch the href value of the <link> nodes at the [YouTube most popular Atom feed](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular).

From the documentation I have read online, this process would be relatively simple, something along the lines of:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular");
XmlNodeList linkNodes;
linkNodes = xml.SelectNodes("/feed/entry/link[@rel='alternate']");
```

But this doesn't work, I get no results. I've tried adding namespaces with an XmlNamespaceManager but that doesn't help, either.

Hasty reply would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure adding namespaces properly *would* help, as I'm sure that's the problem. Personally I'd use LINQ to XML instead though. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string url =
             "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular";
        var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
        var links = doc.Root
                       .Elements(ns + "entry")
                       .Elements(ns + "link")
                       .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("rel") == "alternate");

        Console.WriteLine(links.Count()); // 25
    }
}
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you, I'll give it a go and return with my results.

Comment: +1 My goal this year is to actually use System.Xml.Linq in anger - thanks for the example.

Comment: @dash: I find using any other XML API to be painful these days :)

Comment: I'm just finding it hard to change my ways ;-) having to deliver things quickly means it can be difficult to actually look at new (and better - your expression is so easy to read - very fluent, and namespaces are handled much more elegantly) ways of doing things in the time provided.

Comment: Yes, it works really well, absolutely fantastic! Far more intuitive than using the XmlDocument method!

Comment: @DanielHarrison: It's a darned sight easier to *create* documents than XmlDocument, too...

Answer (score 3):

Jon's answer is definitely the way to go today (or anytime ;-), but if you were interested in what you were doing wrong, then here's an example:

A namespace does exist for your elements, it's the default namespace. Unfortunately, the `XmlDocument` class isn't so elegant in showing you this; instead, you usually 'fake' a namespace prefix mapping onto the root namespace in your document; in this case `xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`

```
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular");

    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("base", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

    var nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("/base:feed/base:entry/base:link[@rel='alternate']", manager);
```

Testing with your live document yields an XmlNodeList containing 25 `link` elements.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I did try something along those lines but I must have messed up somewhere.